# Is there any way of inheriting Bootstrap classes in layouts?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, class

I am adapting a website to use Bootstrap. I was wondering if there was any way of using it so that my HTML elements don't get littered with classes.

I'd like to replace the code below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
        Text
    </div>
</div>
```

With something like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="myClass">
        Text
    </div>
</div>
```

Where `myClass` would inherit the `hidden-xs`, `col-sm-12`, `col-md-4` and `col-md-offset-1` classes.

I've been looking around online seeing if there was any way that I could make my own custom classes "inherit" the bootstrap classes so I can keep the styling in CSS as much as possible, but I can't find anything. I wouldn't be surprised if it's not possible to do, but has anyone got any recommendations or anything on how to make the end result look as clean as it can be?

Thanks

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: No - if you want different widths on each device, then you need to add the classes. There's no getting around it

Comment: You may want to simplify the design to be uniform across devices

Comment: How is this question opinion based? He clearly asks how to inherit css classes, that's not opinion based.

Comment: @Rikudou_Sennin I agree that the question is not really opinion based, but it contains trigger phrases such as _"looking around online"_ and _"has anyone got any recommendations"_ which might cause some people to decide that it is. Perhaps if the OP could reword the last paragraph to remove the chat and focus solely on the problem to be addressed then the  question might get reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly in CSS it's not possible (as far as I know), but it should be possible if you switch to sass (scss).

That being said, I advise against doing so, just repeat the classes and be done with it, that way everyone can tell at first glance what the block will look like.

When you install [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/), you need to download the source files of bootstrap from their [download page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/) and extract the `scss` dir to some directory, e.g. `bootstrap`.

After that create your own stylesheets, let's call it `style.scss` (notice the `scss` extension).

Now in your `style.scss`:

```
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap-grid";

.myClass {
  @extend .col-sm-12;
  @extend .col-md-4;
  // extend any other classes here
}
```

Then you compile your scss file (read `sass` [documentation](https://sass-lang.com/)) and your `myClass` will have all the attributes of classes it extends.

If you never heard of sass before read the documentation first to understand how it works.

Comment: Doing this will add massive bloat to your css files so you're just shifting the bloat from your html to your css

Comment: I had a feeling that this was the case, but thank you for confirming. And I understand that the bloat would simply be shifted in this case, so there's little point to it anyways. But thank you for your answer, and I may just read into SASS a little anyway out of curiosity.

Comment: @Pete yeah, as I said, I advise against doing so, but I just wanted to point out that it is in fact possible.

Comment: @James_P definitely look into sass, you will never want to go back to plain css, just the nesting alone is worth it.